# Download a file received via HTML Response in phonegap (android platform)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am receiving a file from the http response like

```
http://max.com/test/getDoc?file=Zsdeiyigkbmf=asdasdhhghGthDEGB=b==cd
```

the pdf exists in the server and on a successful ajax call returns the path in binary array. It HAS to be encrypted I cannot see the actual path. It fetches and downloads the required pdf file directly after the following code is executed -

```
window.location="http://max.com/test/getDoc?file=Zsdeiyigkbmf=asdasdhhghGthDEGB=b==cd"
```

Now this code works fine on chrome or any other browser. However, the same code doesn't work in phonegap cordova (version 4.2.0). No error, no message from the client.

Comment: use <a download> instead of window.location to point to the url

Comment: did that. works in chrome. nothing in phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

As Cordova 5.0.0, it is required you use the `whitelist` system. As such, you need to know the domainname of the servers you are talking to.

The solution I am going to give you is for general development. This method is NOT for production or final release, as both Google and Apple will **reject** your app; unless you have a very good reason to us this!

This *whitelist* worksheet should help.
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

It is required as of [Cordova Tools 5.0.0](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html) (April 21, 2015).
 For *Phonegap Build*, that means since [`cli-5.1.1`](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/06/16/phonegap-updated-on-build/) (16 Jun 2015)

Add this to your `config.xml`

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"      source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->
```

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**
Add the following to your `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

Comment: And here is a reference of the Content Security Policy: http://content-security-policy.com

Comment: @Joerg You are welcome to copy and redistribute my documents on the `whitelist` system. On `CSP`, this document has more and better references [Whitelist CSP Examples](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-csp-examples.md). None that I have found are complete or completely useful. The one you point to, I was hoping it would be all encompassing. It is not. Since it is an "industry" standard, views vary by the company writing. - links to google,mozilla,html5rocks,dropbox and others.